# How to solve No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in express js?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, cors

I know that this question has been answered and some of them worked but for me it is not. I'm struggling to find a solution for this problem:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://lolcahost:9000/api/users' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I already tried downloading a chrome extension but didn't help me and using **app.use(cors())** also didn't help me.

This is my code in expressjs

```
    /* Importing all necessary packages. */
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/* Default port */
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
/* Creating express object */
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/route'));
app.use(cors());


app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json({
        HOME: "HELLO JSON"
    })
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`)
});
```

and this is my code in vuejs where I'm trying to render the data.

```
getUsers() {
            axios
                .get("http://localhost:9000/api/users/")
                .then(response => (this.results = response.data))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `cors` middlware **AFTER** the `/api` routes. So, actually the `cors` middlware is not even being called. Put the `cors` above other middlwares.

```
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use('/api', require('./routes/route'));
```

Middlwares are called by the order they are initialised. Now, the `/api` is initialised first and is not a middleware(doesn't call the `next()` function) so after the routes any middleware is basically unreachable code.

Comment: Didn't know that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
       next();
    });
```

or

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });
```